# SQL server add default value on join where clause if not record exists

Tags: sql-server, join, case

I have the following SQL server table setup

```
table1.Id
table1.Name

table2.Id
table2.Type
```

There is a 1 to many relationship between `table1` and `table2` eg there can be many records in `table2` that link to a single record in `table1`.

I now have the following dataset:

```
table1  
Id  Name
1   Name1
2   Name2

table2  
Id  Type
1   1
1   2
2   1
```

I now run the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t
LEFT JOIN table2 l
ON t.Id = l.Id
WHERE l.Type = 2
```

And this query will return the following:

```
table1      table2  
Id  Name    Id  Type
1   Name1   1   2
```

What I am actually trying to achieve is a query that will return the following:

```
table1      table2  
Id  Name    Id  Type
1   Name1   1   2
2   Name2   1   DEFAULTVALUE
```

Where I declare the DEFAULTVALUE.

I know if I remove the `WHERE` clause the query will return 3 rows, but I want to exclude all records that do not have a type of 2, and if no records exist I want to add a default entry.

I think I may need to use cases for this, but cannot see exactly how to do this.

I hope my question is clear?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your condition is in `left join` table, you could put it in `left join` clause

```
SELECT  ISNULL(l.Type, 'Default Value') as Type
FROM table1 t
LEFT JOIN table2 l
ON t.Id = l.Id and l.Type = 2
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you try this?  (L.ID would be NULL , not 1 as in your expected output):

```
SELECT T.ID, T.NAME, L.ID, COALESCE(L.TYPE, 'DEFAULTVALUE') AS TYPE
FROM table1 t
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE Type = 2) l ON t.Id = l.Id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `CASE` statement to set the default. You can run the below sample in isolation from your data to test:

```
CREATE TABLE #table1 ( id INT, name VARCHAR(10) );

CREATE TABLE #table2 ( id INT, [type] INT );

INSERT  INTO #table1
        ( id, name )
VALUES  ( 1, 'Name1' ),
        ( 2, 'Name2' );

INSERT  INTO #table2
        ( id, type )
VALUES  ( 1, 1 ),
        ( 1, 2 ),
        ( 2, 1 );

DECLARE @TYPE INT = 2 ,
    @DEFAULT INT = 99;

SELECT  t.id ,
        t.name ,
        l.id ,
        CASE WHEN l.type = @TYPE THEN l.type
             ELSE @DEFAULT
        END AS [Type]
FROM    #table1 t
        LEFT JOIN #table2 l ON t.id = l.id
WHERE   t.id IN ( SELECT    id
                  FROM      #table2
                  WHERE     type = @TYPE );

DROP TABLE #table1;
DROP TABLE #table2;
```